# transform-origin (css) Chrome (88) bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, css-transforms

There are several sources that describes this issue in different ways, but they are too complex (a lot of js) and narrow-focused. And there is no definite answer why does it happens and why Google didn't fix it by now.

I decided to make the most simplest example. Here it is and once again below in snippet: https://codepen.io/backtosoulfire/pen/vYyOJJe

If you are Mozilla user (not only Mozilla I guess) you will find nothing strange and unusual. But if you are exploring the internet with Chrome, try to press marked block.

We have a little transition time and a specific transform-origin property.

```js
let element = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');

element.onclick = function() {
  element.classList.toggle('menu-btn_active');
};
```

```css
.section {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: cyan;
    position: relative;
}

.menu-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; margin-top: -15px;
    left: 50%; margin-left: -50px;
}

.menu-btn_active {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform-origin: left bottom;
}

p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <p>Press me</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will find that rotate is made without considering 'transform-origin' property and at the end of animation the block suddenly "jumps" to a position where it must be if 'transform-origin' was taken into account and effected it.

The quetion sounds like this:

1. Why does it happen?
2. Is there simple way (as simple as the example) to fix it?
3. Should someone contact the Chrome developers with this trouble? Becouse we can find some complex examples of this bug dates several years ago.

P.S. I forgot to share some "strange" "feature". If we resize the element's width at second class, Chrome starts to "render" it like it suppose to. The problem only maintains if the element is the same width.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It isn't a bug, `transform-origin` should be in your original class declaration:

```
.menu-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; margin-top: -15px;
    left: 50%; margin-left: -50px;
    transform-origin: left bottom; // add here
}

.menu-btn_active {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform-origin: left bottom; // remove here
}
```

Initially, the `transform-origin` is set by default. That default is `center center`. You add a class to the item, and *after* the class is added, change the location to `left bottom`, hence the jump.

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/f7b4dab6b40a1ff945b79e11c4ce6863?editors=1100

Comment: Hm... That really solved my "problem" though it doesn't answers why Mozilla behave itself more predictible in that case. Thank you very much! I feel myself stupid because of wasting all the day for that issue but it turned out it wasn's a problem at all, just my carelessness.

Comment: the default is not top left, it's center

Comment: Any idea why Firefox is working with the OP's code? (Which I've verified.) [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) the default is `50% 50% 0`, not `left bottom`. (Also: Remember CSS doesn't do `//` comments.)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh yeah so it is... I've been working with SVG too long!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is a chrome bug, the transition is supposed to work with both transform and transform-origin. Chrome is not hanling the latter. By the way, if you move the transition to the main element it will work when the class is removed (so working only in one direction)

Comment: @TemaniAfif - So this is hiding the problem rather than solving it? (Well, it solves it if the goal is to only animate the one way...)

Comment: @Djave I supplemented my question with "p.s.". Strage behavior happens only if the element's width is not change. If we change it - it starts to work "correct". Though I'm not sure what is correct in this case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes since there is not transform-origin change so no issue.

Comment: @TemaniAfif so did you find any way around to transition transform-origin and transform at the same time on chrome? I swear this was working flawlessly before... seems to still work with safari too!